# Can I add functionality to the Facebook components (plugins)?

Tags: facebook, user-interface

I can add functionality to the Facebook components (plugins)?

Example: Add new functionality in "posts component" (See image)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/face1x.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is "no".... at least this is my understanding